# How to I replace 0 values of features in a dataset, with its median value corresponding to the label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-cleaning

For my Exploratory Data Analysis Project the dataset looks as follows :

[An Image of Dataset for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA5MP.png)

[Link to GitHub Repository for Dataset](https://github.com/ShrinivasSV/Diabetes_EDA_ML/blob/main/diabetes.csv)

The features of my dataset are

- `Pregnancies`
- `Glucose`
- `BloodPressure`
- `SkinThickness`
- `Insulin`
- `BMI`
- `DiabetesPedigreeFunciton`
- `Age`

I want to perform data cleaning, on the numeric features.

And the column `Outcome` is our label,
where value 0 states the patient is NOT diagnosed with diabetes and

We observe that features like `Glucose`, `BloodPressure`, `SkinThickness`, `Insulin` and `BMI` can never be 0.
Hence I wanted to fill the 0 values of the features with the median value, corresponding to their outcome.

Patients records with **Outcome = 0**, will have their 0 values (values that are needed to be treated) replaced by the ***median of respective columns***, where  **Outcome = 0.**

Patients records with **Outcome = 1**, will have their 0 values (values that are needed to be treated) replaced by the ***median of respective columns***, where  **Outcome = 1.**

Essentially I want a way to group the columns according to the `Outcome` label and fill ) values, respectively.

```
def replace_zeros_with_mean(df, col_name):
    df[col_name].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
    mean_value = df[col_name].mean()
    df[col_name].fillna(mean_value, inplace=True)
```

```
replace_zeros_with_mean(new_df, "Glucose")
```

Initially, I performed `mean`, but thought `median` would be a great fit.

```
glucose_group = df["Glucose"].groupby(df["Outcome"])
glucose_group
```

and it resulted something like this

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x7fed9b59df70>
```

I don't know how to proceed and how do I fill `np.nan` values of **records with Outcome = 0**,
with median of **records with Outcome=0** and the same for records with **Outcome = 1**.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your approach in this case.
Go with this flow:

1. Replace your df with np.nan and check it using df.info().

   ```
   df[df.columns[:-1]] = df[df.columns[:-1]].replace(0, np.nan)
   ```
2. Filter the df based on the outcome.

   ```
   df_outcome_0 = df[df['Outcome'] == 0].copy()
   df_outcome_1 = df[df['Outcome'] == 1].copy()
   ```
3. Now replace the NaN values with the median or mean for both the df.

   ```
   df_outcome_0[df.columns[:-1]] = df_outcome_0[df.columns[:-1]].fillna(df_outcome_0[df.columns[:-1]].median())
   df_outcome_1[df.columns[:-1]] = df_outcome_1[df.columns[:-1]].fillna(df_outcome_1[df.columns[:-1]].median())
   ```
4. Finally Concat both the df

   ```
   df_processed = pd.concat([df_outcome_0, df_outcome_1]).sort_index()
   ```